# No way to change bundle ID of existing iOS app?

Tags: ios, app-store

Background:

My company acquired an iOS app from a third party developer. The app is popular in its niche (good ratings and a solid number of users). We want to build on top of that popularity, so although we are rebranding it, we definitely want our future versions to show up as updates of the existing app.

From what I understand, this means we'll have to keep using the existing bundle ID, but that's not great (the existing bundle ID has the previous author's actual name in it, which seems unprofessional for us to keep using). Ideally, we would alias the existing bundle ID with our own new bundle ID (something like com.OurCompanyName.OurNewProductName).

Questions:

a) Am I right to understand that there is absolutely zero chance to change an existing bundle ID? No hidden mechanism to set up aliases, no pleading with the AppStore staff, no exceptions?

b) How embarrassing will it be if we keep using the existing bundle ID forever? Where does the bundle ID actually show up (on device system UI, AppStore web UI, public analytics, etc.)?

c) Am I missing something obvious? Surely, many others have been in this exact situation before us. Is there another way for us to update an existing app but use a more appropriate bundle ID?

Thanks!

Comment: A) correct. The bundle id *is* the app. You can change the name, the icon, the functionality, everything else, but if you change the bundle id it is a different app. B) in general, the user will never see it.  With some effort they can get the ipa off their device and unzip it, but 99.999% of users wouldn’t do that. C). No. See my response to A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) You are correct. The bundle id *is* the app. You can change the name, the icon, the functionality, everything else, but if you change the bundle id it is a different app. It is the internal identifier that iOS uses.

B) In general, the user will never see it. With some effort they can get the IPA off their device and unzip it, but 99.999% of users wouldn’t do that.

C). No. See my response to A

Answer (score 3):

***a)*** *You are right, You have no chance.*

***b)*** *Totally agree*. Good thing is they are not visible in the app url OR while sharing, BUT when it comes to advanced requirement like other app can access your app data OR like share pdf to your app, you need to share your bundle id to other app developers where this old company name that is there in the bundle id will show up.

***c)*** *Totally agree* This is same as option a.

Answer (score 0):

a) The Bundle Identifier is very important for an application, changing it would basically need you to create an entirely new app, which would get rid of any iCloud content of your users.
b) Most users will not see it at all, it is possible but as Paulw11 said, 99.99% of users will not even consider going that way.
c) Sadly, there is no way to change the Bundle Identifier without practically creating a whole new app.
I'm sorry about your very unfortunate situation and I wish you the best in your future endeavours on this task, good luck.